# Change MySQL PDO connection option between queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to change the value of the PDO MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS connection option between queries.

Initially I define the connection handle like:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', $uid, $pwd, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
```

I would like to change the value of MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS to false at some point in the program.  Is that possible?  If so, how is it done?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this command:

```
$dbh->setAttribute("PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS", true);
```

[setAttribute() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)